# SQLAlchemy Relationship

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

i have two tables:

```py
class Item(TimeStampMixin, Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    weight = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    hall = Column(Integer)
    row = Column(Integer)
    stored_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    pickedup_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    billed_until = Column(Date, nullable=True)

    store_job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("job.id"))
    pickup_job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("job.id"))

    store_job = relationship("Job", foreign_keys=[
                             store_job_id], backref="items_to_store")
    pickup_job = relationship(
        "Job", foreign_keys=[pickup_job_id], backref="items_to_pickup")


class Job(TimeStampMixin, Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    job_type = Column(Enum("STORE", "PICKUP", name="job_types"), server_default="STORE")
    planned_for = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    finished_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    started_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
```

currently i can access the items in the job with job.items_to_pickup and job_items_to_store. Since a job can be either store or pickup i trying to find a ways the items will be accessed by just job.items and on a item i want to access the the job by item.job

Is there a smarter way to handle these relationships?